# The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified. multirow

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, multirow

I get the following error when I add more than one row:
The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified. multirow

```
if (tblCari.TblCariAdres.Count != 0) {
    TblCariAdres tblCariAdres = new TblCariAdres();
    foreach (var item in tblCari.TblCariAdres) {
        tblCariAdres.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        tblCariAdres.FirmaId = tblCari1.FirmaId;
        tblCariAdres.CariId = tblCari1.Id;
        tblCariAdres.Tanim = item.Tanim;
        tblCariAdres.Isim = item.Isim;
        tblCariAdres.Adres = item.Adres;
        tblCariAdres.Ilce = item.Ilce;
        tblCariAdres.Sehir = item.Sehir;
        tblCariAdres.Telefon = item.Telefon;
        tblCariAdres.Aciklama = item.Aciklama;

        Db.TblCariAdres.Add(tblCariAdres);
        Db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to set the Id, and it can't be modified - as per the error message you receive

Comment: There is no problem in the first record, when I try to enter two or more records, I get this error

Comment: I missed the first part of your code and I can now see your issue, please see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to add the same variable to the database multiple times. As such your database submission (`Db.SaveChanges()`) is trying to change the `Id` (and other properties) of the existing entity on the second loop.

Try moving this line into the loop: `TblCariAdres tblCariAdres = new TblCariAdres();`

Such that your code looks like the below:

```
if (tblCari.TblCariAdres.Count != 0) {
    foreach (var item in tblCari.TblCariAdres) {
        TblCariAdres tblCariAdres = new TblCariAdres();
        
        tblCariAdres.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        tblCariAdres.FirmaId = tblCari1.FirmaId;
        tblCariAdres.CariId = tblCari1.Id;
        tblCariAdres.Tanim = item.Tanim;
        tblCariAdres.Isim = item.Isim;
        tblCariAdres.Adres = item.Adres;
        tblCariAdres.Ilce = item.Ilce;
        tblCariAdres.Sehir = item.Sehir;
        tblCariAdres.Telefon = item.Telefon;
        tblCariAdres.Aciklama = item.Aciklama;

        Db.TblCariAdres.Add(tblCariAdres);
        Db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```